# Template for common buttons used in the Orbeon Spec

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I am currently trying to create a template for some common buttons used in the Orbeon spec.For Eg: We have 'Print Icon' in all the Orbeon specs developed. 
Can I create the trigger for Print button in some other xml file and call from main Orbeon spec?

Please suggest some ideas on this.

Answer (score 0):

Via [Buttons and Processes](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner%3a-Buttons-and-Processes), you can setup a button which, upon activation, dispatches a custom event.

With [Custom Model Logic](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner%3a-Custom-Model-Logic), you can implement common logic which reacts to this custom event.